# Performance uploading files from S3 to redshift

Tags: python, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Specs:

1. I didn't use COPY TABLE admittedly: my `script.py` pulls S3 objects via `boto3`, processes them, then uses `psycopg2.execute_batch(query, [rows])` to upload an average of 2-5 rows at a time per call. These go into two "raw tables" with no foreign keys or anything. just plain inserts. 20 columns max per table.
2. I used `multiprocessing` Pool `p` of 16 processes. `p.map(fetch_from_s3_upload_to_RS_func, [list of keys of objects in my bucket])`. I declare a [new s3 client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html#multithreading-or-multiprocessing-with-resources) and a [new db connection](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#thread-and-process-safety) inside every subprocess. the function applied to these objects is tiny. The objects are tiny json files.
3. I check the stats on the console, average of 16 concurrent db connections throughout, CPU at 50%. Disk space usage less than 0.1%. The cluster is a single node with dc2.large node type. The machine executing `script.py` is an EC2 m5n.4xlarge. I feel like both these machines are overkill, but what do I know.

Result:
16 hours to insert 12000 rows. Sometimes an `execute_batch` takes up to 3 minutes.

Is this normal? Should i expect this sort of performance as a baseline, given that I know nothing about optimizing postgres databases yet? Any input is appreciated :) this is for a personal project. Please let me know if you need more "clues" for the "puzzle" :)

edit:
fwiw - my suspicions:

- Creating and destroying a new s3 and db client for every function call is bad engineering.
- putting one json objects per S3 object is equally dumb.
- having a 'batch size' of 4 rows per execute_batch statement is also dumb. (Since the data is dirty and some insertions failed i wanted to keep the transaction size small for debugging purposes, still perhaps dumb however)

I realized some pseudocode for my explanations of step 1 and 2 might be helpful.

```py
## pseudocode ##

import psycopg2
import boto3
keys = [...list of keys of s3 objects]
import multiprocessing as mp

with mp.Pool() as p:
    p.map(f, keys)

def f(singular_key):
    s3c = new_s3_client()
    try:
      db = new_db_client()
      json_thing = s3c.getobject(singular_key, 'hardcoded_bucket_name')
      transformed_json_thing = g(json_thing)
      db.batch_execute('insert query', transformed_json)
      db.commit()
     finally:
      db.closeconnection()
   
def g(json):
    return json*2 #some simple computation
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As you've guessed, you need to get rid of the new creation of the clients everytime, especially the DB client. You should see a huge improvement then - if it's still slow, please update the question.

Comment: Hey! So i refactored the code and it sped up quite a bit! however it's still very slow. I'll look to the other guy's answer now to see if i can get even further.

Comment: Good, as expected! Update the question with new code and new stats and we can help more

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak with authority on the python side of this but it does look inefficient to me.

I can speak to Redshift and this pattern is a near anti-pattern.  If I understand you post correctly you are adding 2-3 rows to a table as literals (INSERT INTO X VALUES (...) - basically data embedded in code).  This is a very sub-optimal way to move data into Redshift.  The information comes to the leaders node which compiles and optimizes the code, the query needs to be queued for execution, and then this code is sent to the compute nodes where it is executed as a query and then the data values stored to the compute node disks.  Since these are independent sessions this new data needs to be "COMMITted" which is another queue requiring coordinated leader and compute node actions.  Since the minimal block size on disk for Redshift is 1MB this data will be massively inefficiently stored on disk and will need to be VACUUMed to reclaim the space and performance handicap.

Combined this with the use of a single node for the leader and compute "node" elements creating execution time conflicts and you have a recipe for things moving very slowly.

Next you have many parallel connections working independently which could be filling up the query queues (how do you have these defined), the commit queue which needs to ensure that each session has a coherent version of the table 'as of when its transaction began' which creates a lot of coherency bookkeeping, and the session manager having to create and close potentially many session per second - each of these management factor could also slow things down significantly.  Redshift is made to load and analyze large amounts of data in parallel with clearly delineated code and data paths.  To get this solution to perform well you will need to move the data onto a data input path and likely need to give Redshift large chunks of data as input.